# Get value from address bar or from previous program?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This where I display the id value on the address bar...

```
<a href="view_topic.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></a>
```

And also I pass this value through form...(I have not enclosed the entire form code)

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="add_answer.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td width="18%"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td width="3%">:</td>
<td width="79%"><input name="a_name" type="text" id="a_name" size="45"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><strong>Answer</strong></td>
<td valign="top">:</td>
<td><textarea name="a_answer" cols="45" rows="3" id="a_answer"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>**<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">**</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" name="Submit2" value="Reset"></td>
```

After this we try to retrieve the hidden value from another program...

```
// get value of id that sent from address bar 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id='$id'";
```

which does not work..that is the selected id and its corresponding values in the table is not displayed...instead the whole table is displayed

Am I missing something??? Please Help!!!

Comment: Echo out $sql and see the query you are running. Run that query directly in the database and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a way of accessing the parameter that works whether it's a POST field or a URL parameter, use `$_REQUEST`:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using   `method="post"` in form then  try `$id=$_POST['id'];`

Comment: indeed. otherwise the id should be included in the form action attribute value.

Comment: Depends on server conf

Comment: @Pye Anyone who configures their server to put post variables somewhere other than `$_POST` is perverse, and can safely be ignored.

Comment: @Barmar I mean, if you set `register_globals = on`, you could use `$id` instead of `$_GET['id']` or `$_POST['id']` (which involve security issues !)

Comment: @Pye I thought you were saying that server configuration could prevent `$_POST['id']` from working.